# LXC is returning an error when creating new unprivileged containers

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, lxc

I recently migrated to a new server (Ubuntu 14.04, dedicated, not virtual) and installed LXC 1.1.2. I had LXC set up on my previous server without any trouble but on the new server I'm consistently running into a problem with creating new unprivileged containers (as well as not being able to start migrated containers). With a newly-created user account, I consistently get the following error:

```
unshare: Operation not permitted
read pipe: Permission denied
lxc-create: lxccontainer.c: do_create_container_dir: 778 Failed to chown container dir
lxc-create: lxc_create.c: main: 274 Error creating container container-template-ubuntu-14.04-7
```

I followed some of the instructions here: https://www.stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/ and poked around in `/proc/sys/kernel/` but this doesn't seem to have helped. I'm not sure what else I can try.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Debian 9 and this thread was always on top of duckduckgo results, so I do appology for giving a solution about a Debian problem on askubuntu but it may help Ubuntu users as well :

After having installed LXC (`apt install lxc`) just check the result of this command :

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone
```

If it's `0`, then you may need to do this :

```
# echo "kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1" > /etc/sysctl.d/80-lxc-userns.conf
# sysctl --system
```

I saw this "trick" on [the LXC page of Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC) and it worked for me.

Note: If it doesn't solve the problem for you, just remove `/etc/sysctl.d/80-lxc-userns.conf` and run `sysctl --system` again to cancel this change.

Comment: This still works.  I missed that piece of information on the Debian page.  Was my last piece of the puzzle. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it wasn't working turned out to be the kernel which was supplied with the Ubuntu build installed by the hosting provider (SoYouStart/OVH). This kernel has less features enabled, including the ones required by LXC. I had installed a Generic Linux kernel, but not correctly updated grub and enabled it.

After following the steps for selecting the generic kernel and updating grub and rebooting, LXC worked as expected. I hope that helps someone in a similar situation.

Comment: I've hit the same issue with stock Debian Jessie kernel (3.16 and 4.1 from backports). Could you please provide more details on what was missing?

Comment: That would take a little bit of work (which I can't do right now) but certainly much less features enabled than the Generic Linux kernel, probably for security and stability. I think the main offenders were around cgroups and security.